# Remove entry from top links (after malware)

Tags: magento-1, toplinks

I had a malware on my page and after that the entry "Our Team" appears on the top linke of my page www.worg.ch.
I would like to remove this link again.
I was looking for local.xml but I cannot find the file :-(
I also checked customer.xml and checkout.xml but there is no such entry in the file.
Magento Version: 1.9.0.1
Any idea how to remove this entry?

[image]

[image]

**head.phtml**:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php echo $this->getContentType() ?>" />
```

getTitle() ?>
getDescription()) ?>" />
getKeywords()) ?>" />
getRobots()) ?>" />
getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
getFaviconFile(); ?>" type="image/x-icon" />

//helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('blank.html') ?>';
    var BLANK_IMG = 'helper('core/js')->getJsUrl('spacer.gif') ?>';
//]]>

getCssJsHtml() ?>
getChildHtml() ?>
helper('core/js')->getTranslatorScript() ?>
getIncludes() ?>

**header.phtml**:

```
<div class="header">
```

getChildHtml('welcome') ?> getAdditionalHtml() ?>
            getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        
        getChildHtml('headerCart') ?>
        getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
    
    
        getIsHomePage()):?>
        **getLogoAlt() ?>**getUrl('') ?>" title="getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo">getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="getLogoAlt() ?>" />
        
        getUrl('') ?>" title="getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo">**getLogoAlt() ?>**getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="getLogoAlt() ?>" />
        
        **__('Skip to Main Content') ?> »**
        getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>

        getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
    
    
     getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>

**links.phtml**:

```
<?php $_links = $this->getLinks(); ?>
```

0): ?>
getName()): ?> id="getName() ?>">
    
        
            toHtml() ?>
        
            getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="getIsFirst()): ?>firstgetIsLast()): ?> last" getLiParams() ?>>getBeforeText() ?>getUrl() ?>" title="getTitle() ?>" getAParams() ?>>getLabel() ?>getAfterText() ?>

**linksblock.phtml**:

```
<li<?php if($this->getIsFirst()||$this->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($this->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($this->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $this->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $this->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getLinkUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $this->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $this->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $this->getAfterText() ?></li>
```

Comment: try this file `app/design/frontend/your theme package/theme/template/page/template/links.phtml`

Comment: I have added the 4 different files head.phtml, header.phtml, links.phtml and linksblock.phtml. I do not see anything abnormal :-( Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in here If you see any unknown scripts remove them from below configuration.

```
Configuration->General->Design->HTML Head->Miscellaneous Scripts
Configuration->General->Design->Footer->Miscellaneous HTML
```

Comment: No scripts present.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can check in below files

`app/design/frontend/yourPackage/yourTheme/template/page/html/header.phtml`

and also check.

`app/design/frontend/yourPackage/yourTheme/template/page/html/head.phtml`

and also check.

`app/design/frontend/yourPackage/yourTheme/template/page/template/links.phtml`

**And if you not find this things in above file then follow this step**

You can on your path hint from admin and heck the template and its block for all section of the page.

`Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer`

Select the store from `Current Configuration` Scope drop-down from top left section below navigation.
    Than go to `Debug -> Template Path Hint` and set it to `Yes`.
    Refresh the fron-tend page, You will get the all page path.

In this way you come to know if any custom module install and override any phtml then also you will get the path of that file.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find any entry in the 3 above mentioned files :-)

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Thank you. I already tried that but without success. It should be the header.phtml right?

Comment: it should be there only check one by one html tags and check

Comment: I have checked all displayed files. Found nothing. From which file does it get the links?
<li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if...

Comment: Is there a possibility to upload my phtml files?